# How to install the PHP agent for New Relic if I don't have root access to Heroku server?

Tags: php, heroku, web

I've an app on Heroku and installed the add-on on the Heroku website. When I click on it, I'm brought to the new New Relic account where the instructions are for installing the agent. So how does one set up the agent for the Heroku server?

I'm new to this, so bare that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

No need to install it; you can simply ignore those instructions. You'll notice as you push that Heroku automatically enables the extension; it installs and launches the agent too. Also see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#php-5-5 where the auto-enabling is documented.